# Is there a way to loop through all elements of a vector in parallel in C++?

Tags: c++

I am working on an elevator simulator in c++. I have a class *passenger* and the program creates "randomized" instances of that class with different starting floors and different destinations within the building then stores them in a vector

```
vector<passenger> passengers;
```

I am working on the dispatch algorithm for the 4 elevators in the building. However, because of the fact that the algorithm compares all 4 elevators in the building, it is possible that the passenger cannot have an elevator assigned right away (i.e. not available IDLE elevator or elevator having enough space going in the same direction as the passenger).

***Problem***:

I want to apply the algorithm constantly to all the elements of the vector passengers simultaneously and can't do it with a traditional for loop as it could get stuck mid-way with passenger instances down the vector that could be assigned an elevator left waiting.

Anyone knows if there is a way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a parallel [ExecutionPolicy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).

Do note that if you need to synchronize access to elements, executing in parallel may end up being *slower* than serial execution.

Comment: Are parallel execution policies actually already implemented by any mainstream compiler?

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to this. But from what I understand you mean that if if have per example two instances of the passenger class going to the same level and have the same starting destination, and if the only one elevator is going in the same direction and only has one space left - it might be slower to decide which passenger should take the elevator? And do you mean slower for the passengers or for the program run time?

Comment: @Konrad Intel has [an implementation](https://github.com/intel/parallelstl) and I believe they contributed it to llvm and gcc already.

Comment: @Quentin_P I meant "slower program run time".

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, a simple infinite loop might be neater. I'll just implement that if it hasn't found a match directly, the loop will have to skip to the next element of the vector to see if it's possible for it to be assigned an elevator. Then at the last element for the loop to start from the top again.

Comment: @KonradRudolph MSVC has an article on their implementation here... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/